Jenkins latest update bricked system
My Jenkins instance is currently broken.
This is not an exhaustive list, but here are some of the issues. As a result, I cannot see any of the jobs or workspaces anymore, although they are still there on the file system:
Plugin errors1
Plugin errors2
I am uploading the current config as per this guide:
https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2024/06/11/require-java-17/#reporting-issues
Jenkins: 2.462.3
OS: Linux - 5.10.0-33-cloud-amd64
Java: 11.0.17 - BellSoft (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM)
---
antisamy-markup-formatter:162.v0e6ec0fcfcf6
apache-httpcomponents-client-4-api:4.5.14-208.v438351942757
asm-api:9.7.1-97.v4cc844130d97
authorize-project:1.8.1
bouncycastle-api:2.30.1.78.1-248.ve27176eb_46cb_
caffeine-api:3.1.8-133.v17b_1ff2e0599
command-launcher:116.vd85919c54a_d6
commons-httpclient3-api:3.1-3
commons-lang3-api:3.17.0-84.vb_b_938040b_078
commons-text-api:1.12.0-129.v99a_50df237f7
durable-task:581.v299a_5609d767
eddsa-api:0.3.0-4.v84c6f0f4969e
extensible-choice-parameter:1.8.1
flatpickr-api:4.6.13-5.v534d8025a_a_59
groovy:457.v99900cb_85593
gson-api:2.11.0-85.v1f4e87273c33
instance-identity:201.vd2a_b_5a_468a_a_6
ionicons-api:74.v93d5eb_813d5f
jackson2-api:2.17.0-379.v02de8ec9f64c
jakarta-activation-api:2.1.3-1
jakarta-mail-api:2.1.3-1
javax-activation-api:1.2.0-7
javax-mail-api:1.6.2-10
jaxb:2.3.9-1
jdk-tool:80.v8a_dee33ed6f0
joda-time-api:2.13.0-93.v9934da_29b_a_e9
jquery3-api:3.7.1-2
json-api:20240303-101.v7a_8666713110
json-path-api:2.9.0-118.v7f23ed82a_8b_8
matrix-auth:3.2.3
mina-sshd-api-common:2.14.0-133.vcc091215a_358
mina-sshd-api-core:2.14.0-133.vcc091215a_358
pipeline-model-api:2.2218.v56d0cda_37c72
script-security:1369.v9b_98a_4e95b_2d
snakeyaml-api:2.3-123.v13484c65210a_
sshd:3.330.vc866a_8389b_58
structs:338.v848422169819
token-macro:400.v35420b_922dcb_
trilead-api:2.147.vb_73cc728a_32e
variant:60.v7290fc0eb_b_cd
workflow-scm-step:427.v4ca_6512e7df1
workflow-step-api:678.v3ee58b_469476


java -version
openjdk version "11.0.17" 2022-10-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.17+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.17+7-LTS, mixed mode)


uname -a
Linux jenkins-1-poc-vm 5.10.0-33-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.226-1 (2024-10-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux

I am unable to create a JIRA as I am not able to sign up for an account.
Please advise on how best to resolve.
Is there a way to rollback all plugins to their equivalent version that is compatible with 2.462.3?
I have Jenkins deployed using bitnami.
Or perhaps there is a way to simply migrate the configs to a new instance?

Was on 2.479.1 with Java 11 with no issues

Attempted upgrade of .war to 2.479.2 → failed expecting Java 17

Attempted rollback to 2.479.1 (previous functional version) → failed expecting Java 17

Rollback to older versions works up to and including 2.462.3 in a semi-broken state (can login to Jenkins, but everything is corrupted)

Since we were on 2.479.1 with Java 11 our system is now bricked. We should be on Java 17 which is incompatible with our configs.

I also attempted the upgrade to Java 17, and it still does not work.


